# MS VSTS Rest API's: Get List of Attachments for a given item

Tags: rest, api, azure, wiql

Using the Azure API's, I am able to get the content of an attachment using:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/attachments/{id}?api-version=4.1`

This assumes you know the guid (id) of the attachment you wish to download.

What I am trying to do is for a given workItem ID, get a list of ALL attachments (including the ID). Anyone know what the easiest way to achieve this is?

Answer (score 0):

I find this Azure API may be helpful for you.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=4.1
```

For more details, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

Comment: Are you sure that lists all attachements? I tried this but could not see them!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$expand=Relations` in the Api-Url

E.g. `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&$expand=Relations&api-version=4.1`